# Miner quit working this morning

Tags: miner-configuration, quarkcoin

CPU mining for Quark coins for the last few days, (just doing it for fun, I know they're practically worthless) been working with no issues. This morning I wake up and look at my wallet and the last transaction shows as completed at 7:26 AM 22 DEC 13 and nothing follows that transaction. I've tried stopping and restarting everything, viewed my logs, reviewed my settings, checked with the pool to make sure they're still up.... everything seems to be in order. I'm still relatively new to all of this so if anyone could help me think of some troubleshooting tasks I haven't taken, it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more of info would have been helpful...
Let's see, if you mention your wallet, I understand that you're mining by having your wallet mining for you (solo-mining) and not via a pool. In case this were to be true, you'd have to make sure that your wallet is up to date and that you have at least one or two nodes listed in your conf file.

In case you were mining via a pool, I'd make sure the pool is still up. The fact you don't see any new transactions could be for two reasons: 
1) The power you put to solo-mine is not enough anymore, difficulty has risen too much and your computer can't mine efficiently anymore.
2) Check that you're still really synchronised with the blockchain.

Hope it helps.